# Unexpected zeros when performing file I/O

Tags: c, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have a program that I would like to take individual characters from lines in a text source file and store them in a two-dimensional array (which I call `numbers[][N]`). After all the chars from my source file are stored in `numbers`, I sum the `N` individual columns of `numbers` into another array, called `temp[N]`.

The problem is, after I determine the longest line in my source text and the total number of lines, I reset my file pointer and use `fgetc()` to pull in the individual characters one at a time and store their values in an element of `numbers`.  But in this implementation I'm getting odd strings of zeros (integer literal `0`) stored in `numbers` where there should be non-zero values. Why?

Text of the source file `sumSource.txt` can be found 
[here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13)

*Note: I've managed to induce the appropriate behavior with a different implementation, but I want to know why **this** code gives me weird strings of zeros.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a sourcefile here
#define SOURCE_FILE "/home/demiurge/play/euler/sumSource.txt"

int main(void)
{
    // generic indices
    int i, j, k;

    // open a stream to sourcefile here
    FILE* _Fsource = fopen( SOURCE_FILE, "r" );

    // Determine the longest number of digits in any line
    // _Fsource and the total number of terms in the sum.
    int ROWS = 0;
    int COLS = 0;

    // Recent char from sourcefile
    int c;

    do { // I'm doing this do/while statement so that 'count' is automatic

        int count = 0;
        while ( ( c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) != EOF ) {
            if( c == '\n' ) {
                ROWS++;
                if( COLS < count ) {
                    COLS = count;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    } while ( c != EOF );

    // Reset position of _Fsource to start of
    // sourcefile
    fseek( _Fsource, 0L, SEEK_SET );

    // create a storage mechanism for
    // the partial sum of the numbers
    // in sourcefile
    int numbers[ROWS][COLS];
    int temp[COLS];

    // set every element in temp to zero
    for ( i = 0; i < COLS; i++ ) {
        temp[i] = 0;
    }

// THINGS GO PEAR-SHAPED HERE; WHY?
    for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS && \
            ( c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) != '\n'; j++ ) {

            numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            temp[j] += numbers[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to read the source file to get the longest number or the total nember of terms as it is a given data of the problem: 100 numbers of 50 digits.

Comment: @Bob__ I'm just playing around with more general implementations for the problem.  What if the method I use here is useful later?

Comment: Ok, in that case you should consider the alignment of the numbers too. ;)

Comment: `_Fsource` is a reserved identifier, suggest `_fsource` or something instead

Comment: The outer `do` loop is redundant as its exit condition always fails

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and a capital letter (or another underscore) are reserved for use by the implementation.  You are part of the implementation; you should not use names such as `_Fsource`.  Names starting with an underscore and anything else are also reserved for the implementation — it is best not to start your own names with underscores.

Comment: You should be checking whether `c == EOF` in the inner loop where 'things go pear shaped'.  Especially if there's any danger that the input file does not terminate with a newline.

Comment: `COLS` is the length of the longest line, but when you read the file later you leave uninitialized a bunch of characters on lines that were shorter than the longest line.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any output so how are you determining that things "went pear shaped" ?

Comment: If the file is large (> 100K perhaps) then you may cause a stack overflow , it might be better to malloc the array

Comment: @M.M: want to bet on an infinite loop because the code isn't detecting EOF but is getting EOF which is not the same as newline so the loop continues?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are many problems indeed. `j < COLS`will prevent any infinite loop though and `EOF - '0'` wouldn't produce zeroes in the output (not that there is any output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE #2:** Found the **real** problem:  Alternate rows of the input loop were *not* being filled with data.  The reading of the *even* row would be fulfilled on column count but would *not* absorb its corresponding newline.  The following *odd* row would see an *immediate* newline and terminate without storing any data

---

I cleaned up your code and added output print [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].  Of note was the fragility of the "PEAR SHAPED" loop if lines were short or encountered premature EOF.  I've also provided a fix for the "even/odd" bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a sourcefile here
//#define SOURCE_FILE "/home/demiurge/play/euler/sumSource.txt"
#define SOURCE_FILE "sumSource.txt"

int
main(void)
{
    // generic indices
    int icol;
    int irow;

    int nlflg;

    // open a stream to sourcefile here
    FILE *_Fsource = fopen(SOURCE_FILE, "r");

    // Determine the longest number of digits in any line
    // _Fsource and the total number of terms in the sum.
    int ROWS = 0;
    int COLS = 0;

    // Recent char from sourcefile
    int c;

    // I'm doing this do/while statement so that 'count' is automatic
    do {
        int count = 0;

        while (1) {
            c = fgetc(_Fsource);
            if (c == EOF)
                break;

            if (c == '\n') {
                ROWS++;
                if (COLS < count)
                    COLS = count;
                count = 0;
            }
            else
                count++;
        }
    } while (0);

    printf("ROWS=%d COLS=%d\n",ROWS,COLS);

    // Reset position of _Fsource to start of
    // sourcefile
    fseek(_Fsource, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // create a storage mechanism for
    // the partial sum of the numbers
    // in sourcefile
    int numbers[ROWS][COLS];
    int temp[COLS];

    // set every element in temp to zero
    for (icol = 0; icol < COLS; icol++)
        temp[icol] = 0;

    // in case of some lines are "short"
    for (irow = 0; irow < ROWS; irow++) {
        for (icol = 0; icol < COLS; icol++)
            numbers[irow][icol] = 0;
    }

    // THINGS GO PEAR-SHAPED HERE; WHY?
    c = EOF;
    for (irow = 0; irow < ROWS; irow++) {
        nlflg = 0;

        for (icol = 0; icol < COLS; icol++) {
            c = fgetc(_Fsource);
            if (c == EOF)
                break;

            // NOTE: in original code, this would cause alternate loop to
            // terminate due to "off-by-one" error
            // that is, even loops would fail to absorb their newlines and
            // cause odd loops to terminate without storing anything
            if (c == '\n') {
                nlflg = 1;
                break;
            }

            if (irow < 5)
                printf("DEBUG/READ: %d,%d c=%2.2X/%d\n",irow,icol,c,c - '0');
            numbers[irow][icol] = (c - '0');
        }

        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        // NOTE: without this, every alternate row would be skipped
        if (! nlflg) {
            while (1) {
                c = fgetc(_Fsource);
                if (c == EOF)
                    break;
                if (c == '\n')
                    break;
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }

    for (irow = 0; irow < ROWS; irow++) {
        for (icol = 0; icol < COLS; icol++)
            temp[icol] += numbers[irow][icol];
    }

    for (icol = 0; icol < COLS; icol++)
        printf("%d: %d\n",icol,temp[icol]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I ran your original code [with output statements] and mine.  Here's the difference:

```
--- /tmp/orig   2015-12-27 17:45:57.700757183 -0800
+++ /tmp/fixed  2015-12-27 17:45:14.236833644 -0800
@@ -49,153 +49,253 @@
 DEBUG/READ: 0,47 c=32/2
 DEBUG/READ: 0,48 c=35/5
 DEBUG/READ: 0,49 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,0 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 2,1 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,0 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 1,1 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,2 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 1,3 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,4 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,5 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 1,6 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 1,7 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,8 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,9 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,10 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,11 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 1,12 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 1,13 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,14 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,15 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,16 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 1,17 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,18 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 1,19 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 1,20 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,21 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 1,22 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 1,23 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 1,24 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 1,25 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 1,26 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 1,27 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 1,28 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,29 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 1,30 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,31 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,32 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,33 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,34 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 1,35 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,36 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 1,37 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,38 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 1,39 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 1,40 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 1,41 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,42 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 1,43 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 1,44 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 1,45 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 1,46 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 1,47 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 1,48 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 1,49 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 2,0 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,1 c=34/4
 DEBUG/READ: 2,2 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 2,3 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,4 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 2,3 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,4 c=34/4
 DEBUG/READ: 2,5 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 2,6 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 2,7 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,8 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 2,9 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,10 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,11 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 2,12 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 2,13 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,14 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,15 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,16 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 2,17 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,18 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 2,19 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 2,20 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 2,21 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 2,22 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 2,23 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 2,24 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 2,25 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 2,26 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 2,27 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 2,28 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 2,29 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 2,30 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,31 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 2,6 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 2,7 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 2,8 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 2,9 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,10 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,11 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 2,12 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,13 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 2,14 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,15 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 2,16 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 2,17 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 2,18 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 2,19 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,20 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 2,21 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,22 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 2,23 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,24 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 2,25 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 2,26 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 2,27 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 2,28 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,29 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 2,30 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 2,31 c=33/3
 DEBUG/READ: 2,32 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,33 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,33 c=35/5
 DEBUG/READ: 2,34 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 2,35 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,36 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 2,37 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,38 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 2,39 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 2,40 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 2,41 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 2,35 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 2,36 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,37 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 2,38 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,39 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,40 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 2,41 c=36/6
 DEBUG/READ: 2,42 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 2,43 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 2,44 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 2,45 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 2,46 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 2,47 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 2,48 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 2,49 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 4,0 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 4,1 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 4,2 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 4,3 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 4,4 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 4,5 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,43 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 2,44 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 2,45 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 2,46 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 2,47 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 2,48 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 2,49 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 3,0 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 3,1 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,2 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 3,3 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 3,4 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,5 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,6 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,7 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,8 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,9 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 3,10 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,11 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,12 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 3,13 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 3,14 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,15 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 3,16 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,17 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,18 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 3,19 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,20 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,21 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,22 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,23 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 3,24 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,25 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 3,26 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,27 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 3,28 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,29 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 3,30 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 3,31 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,32 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 3,33 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,34 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,35 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 3,36 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 3,37 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,38 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 3,39 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 3,40 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 3,41 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 3,42 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,43 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 3,44 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 3,45 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 3,46 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 3,47 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 3,48 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 3,49 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 4,0 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 4,1 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 4,2 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 4,3 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 4,4 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,5 c=35/5
 DEBUG/READ: 4,6 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 4,7 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 4,8 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 4,9 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 4,10 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 4,7 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 4,8 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 4,9 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 4,10 c=37/7
 DEBUG/READ: 4,11 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 4,12 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 4,13 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 4,14 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,12 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 4,13 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 4,14 c=33/3
 DEBUG/READ: 4,15 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 4,16 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 4,17 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 4,18 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 4,19 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 4,20 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 4,16 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 4,17 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 4,18 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,19 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 4,20 c=31/1
 DEBUG/READ: 4,21 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 4,22 c=34/4
-DEBUG/READ: 4,23 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 4,24 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 4,25 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 4,22 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 4,23 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 4,24 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 4,25 c=30/0
 DEBUG/READ: 4,26 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 4,27 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 4,28 c=39/9
-DEBUG/READ: 4,29 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 4,30 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 4,31 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 4,27 c=31/1
+DEBUG/READ: 4,28 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 4,29 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 4,30 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 4,31 c=31/1
 DEBUG/READ: 4,32 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 4,33 c=35/5
-DEBUG/READ: 4,34 c=38/8
-DEBUG/READ: 4,35 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 4,36 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 4,33 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 4,34 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,35 c=35/5
+DEBUG/READ: 4,36 c=31/1
 DEBUG/READ: 4,37 c=33/3
 DEBUG/READ: 4,38 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 4,39 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 4,40 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 4,41 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 4,42 c=31/1
-DEBUG/READ: 4,43 c=37/7
-DEBUG/READ: 4,44 c=33/3
-DEBUG/READ: 4,45 c=30/0
-DEBUG/READ: 4,46 c=39/9
+DEBUG/READ: 4,39 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,40 c=38/8
+DEBUG/READ: 4,41 c=30/0
+DEBUG/READ: 4,42 c=36/6
+DEBUG/READ: 4,43 c=33/3
+DEBUG/READ: 4,44 c=32/2
+DEBUG/READ: 4,45 c=34/4
+DEBUG/READ: 4,46 c=36/6
 DEBUG/READ: 4,47 c=36/6
-DEBUG/READ: 4,48 c=32/2
-DEBUG/READ: 4,49 c=39/9
-0: 189301617
-1: 98463
-2: -536821826
-3: 65685
-4: 1149687807
-5: 33045
-6: -330672558
-7: 309
-8: 1149933361
-9: 495
-10: 715103802
-11: 33063
-12: -739952904
-13: 33225
-14: 1041326090
-15: 98512
-16: 723772574
-17: 65884
-18: -700583228
-19: 65755
-20: 1151592341
-21: 33082
-22: 635881077
-23: 98456
-24: 1670167446
-25: 65939
-26: 1352358526
-27: 32936
-28: -1507047068
-29: 131126
-30: 28632144
-31: 3670307
-32: -1457728577
-33: 5013884
-34: 1632187
-35: 202
-36: 890045461
-37: 354
-38: -1232222461
-39: 349
-40: 518640906
-41: 33102
-42: -538593328
-43: 65655
-44: 1803206122
-45: 33018
-46: 429048077
-47: 335
-48: 1669065150
-49: 65900
+DEBUG/READ: 4,48 c=37/7
+DEBUG/READ: 4,49 c=36/6
+0: 506
+1: 428
+2: 443
+3: 452
+4: 503
+5: 480
+6: 474
+7: 441
+8: 446
+9: 432
+10: 422
+11: 440
+12: 436
+13: 469
+14: 426
+15: 454
+16: 447
+17: 453
+18: 453
+19: 419
+20: 486
+21: 392
+22: 484
+23: 394
+24: 482
+25: 476
+26: 462
+27: 409
+28: 487
+29: 512
+30: 427
+31: 464
+32: 466
+33: 487
+34: 454
+35: 427
+36: 458
+37: 443
+38: 455
+39: 470
+40: 410
+41: 449
+42: 441
+43: 468
+44: 486
+45: 478
+46: 462
+47: 460
+48: 425
+49: 422
```

Answer (score 1):

You use unallocated memory on `numbers`. You must use `malloc` or use this:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS ; j++ ) {
          numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

This helps at my gcc. Your full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a sourcefile here
#define SOURCE_FILE "/tmp/src.txt"

int main(void)
{
    // generic indices
    int i, j, k;

    // open a stream to sourcefile here
    FILE* _Fsource = fopen( SOURCE_FILE, "r" );

    // Determine the longest number of digits in any line
    // _Fsource and the total number of terms in the sum.
    int ROWS = 0;
    int COLS = 0;

    // Recent char from sourcefile
    int c;

    do { // I'm doing this do/while statement so that 'count' is automatic

        int count = 0;
        while ( ( c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) != EOF ) {
            if( c == '\n' ) {
                ROWS++;
                if( COLS < count ) {
                    COLS = count;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    } while ( c != EOF );

    // Reset position of _Fsource to start of
    // sourcefile
    fseek( _Fsource, 0L, SEEK_SET );

    // create a storage mechanism for
    // the partial sum of the numbers
    // in sourcefile
    int numbers[ROWS][COLS];
    int temp[COLS];

    // set every element in temp to zero
    for ( i = 0; i < COLS; i++ ) {
        temp[i] = 0;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS ; j++ ) {
          numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
// THINGS GO PEAR-SHAPED HERE; WHY?
    for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS && \
            ( c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) != '\n'; j++ ) {

            numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            temp[j] += numbers[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the matrix would have been unallocated if I had declared it as an `int** matrix` or `int* matrix[N]`; as is it I think the matrix is merely uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping rows when reading and your matrix is uninitialized. I get correct values rewriting the loop like this (all the rows in source file have the same lenght):

```
for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
    j = 0;
    while( (c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) >= '0'  &&  c <= '9') {
        numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );
        j++;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment, I also would like to address you to the possible bug coming from a source file with lines of different length. How do you consider the missing digits? For example, having:

```
1234
123
```

the result is `2464` (`=1234+1230`) or `1357` (`=1234+123`)?

In the first case you should properly initialize all the elements:

```
for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; (c = fgetc( source ) ) >='0' && c<='9'; j++ ) {
        numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );            
    }
    while ( j < COLS ) {
        numbers[i][j] = 0;
        j++;
    }
}
```

For the second case you can shift the elements:

```
for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; (c = fgetc( source ) ) >='0' && c<='9'; j++ ) {
        numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );            
    }
    if ( j == 0 ) {                         // bad input
        for ( int k = 0; k < COLS; k++ ) {
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    } else if ( j < COLS ) {
        int d = COLS - j;
        int k;
        for ( k = COLS-1; k >= d; k-- ) {
            numbers[i][k] = numbers[i][k-d];
        }
        while ( k >= 0 ) {
        numbers[i][k] = 0;
        k--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only the first part of a more general solution, and doesn't represent a complete program (note the complete lack of error checking and almost no attention to memory safety :).  The problem of lines of unequal length is solved later; this stub of code merely maps a string of characters from the text input into a corresponding set of integer literals in a matrix for easier manipulation.  I intend to reorient the numbers so that they're represented in little-endian fashion. That way the indices reflect the appropriate power of ten.

Comment: @HandsomeGorilla: That makes sense, but if you are implementing something like bignumbers a base greater then ten is usually more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialize all the matrix to 0 if you want to perform column sums.

Then keep in mind that every line of your source file ends with "\r\n" and not just with "\n".
You can adjust your code like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < COLS && \
        ( c = fgetc( _Fsource ) ) != '\r'; j++ ) {//stops at \r
        numbers[i][j] = ( c - '0' );
    }
    c = fgetc(_Fsource);//read \n
}
```

Comment: Reading `\r\n` in a file would only occur if a Windows text file is opened on a non-Windows OS, so this code would just break in most situations. If you want to handle that case that's fine but your code must also cope with lines ending only in `\n`.

Comment: @M.M The ending doesn't depends on the OS rather then on the text-encoding.

Comment: @Alex44true, but in practice the only systems that exist are Windows (\r\n), old Macs (\r) and everything else (\n)